# Audio Post from iPhone to WCF service, audio is saved but not playing. Why?

Tags: ios, iphone, wcf, audio, multipart

I am sending audio from iphone to wcf service using post method for audio transfer and then audio is saved but saved audio is not playing.

//Service

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, UriTemplate = "Upload/?FileName={FileName}")]
bool Upload(Stream fileStream, string FileName);
```

//Method for Upload Audio

```
public bool Upload(Stream fileStream, string FileName)
        {
            try
            {
                string FolderPath = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Audio\\";
                if (!Directory.Exists(FolderPath))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(FolderPath);
                }

                FileStream fileToupload = new FileStream(FolderPath + FileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);

                byte[] bytearray = new byte[1000000];
                int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;

                while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytesRead); // Write directly to the file
                    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                }
                fileToupload.Close();
                fileToupload.Dispose();

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

//iPhone Code

```
-(void)uploadAudioFile{
    if([WMUtility isNetConnected]){

        NSData *fileData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Upload/?FileName=%@",WM_APP_WEBSERVICE_URL,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eNableMobileAudio_%@.caf",dateTime]] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

        NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
        NSMutableData *body = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"audioFile\"; filename=\"eNableMobileAudio_%@.caf\"\r\n",dateTime] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        //[soundFileURL lastPathComponent]
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:fileData];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [request setHTTPBody:body];
        NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"application/octet-stream/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
        [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

        NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[body bytes]]);

        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
    }
}
```

Comment: where's the code to play the audio?

Comment: an audio file is save on folder and when i play the audio it is not playing means audio is in corrupt format.

Comment: Looks like you're converting  the bytes to a string for transport. Are you converting the string back to a byte array on the host side? Doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: Data is sending from iPhone side, i can receive in stream and convert this to byte array and right on file and file is save with data but when i play this on vlc, this file is not playing.